# How can I get the active tab index in tab panel?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

How can I get the active or selected tab index in tab panel in sencha touch?

I am using `tabpanel` in my application.

Comment: Could you provide us what you have already tried?

Comment: Removed the tag from the title and made it a question; removed duplicate sentence; removed 'thank you' fluff. Still needs examples of what the OP has tried, and how it fails them.

Comment: Also, with these edits, the body is little more than a restatement of the title. Some more details would be useful

Answer (score 7):

```
var tabpanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mainViewport #mainTabPanel'); //use your item Id / reference here
var activeTab = tabpanel.getActiveTab();
var activeTabIndex = tabpanel.items.indexOf(activeTab);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to use:

```
tabpanel.getActiveItem();
```

Was getting this error on getActiveTab:

> getActiveTab is not a function

Answer (score 3):

```
var activeTab = tabPanel.getActiveTab();
var currentStep = tabPanel.items.indexOf(activeTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct code:

```
getTabIndex: function(tab) {
    var index = 0;

    tab.up('#mainTabPanel').getItems().each(function(item) {
        if (tab === item) {
            return false;
        }

        if (item.tab) {
            index++;
        }
    });

    return index;
}
```